# How to use component store with composition in ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

In the ngrx [component-store docs](https://next.ngrx.io/guide/component-store/initialization) they use inheritance in their examples:

```
export interface MoviesState {
  movies: Movie[];
}

@Injectable()
export class MoviesStore extends ComponentStore<MoviesState> {
  
  constructor() {
    super({movies: []});
  }
}

-- OR --

@Component({
  template: `
    <li *ngFor="let movie of (movies$ | async)">
      {{ movie.name }}
    </li>
  `,
  providers: [ComponentStore],
})
export class MoviesPageComponent {
  readonly movies$ = this.componentStore.select(state => state.movies);
 
  constructor(
    private readonly componentStore: ComponentStore<{movies: Movie[]}>
  ) {}
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.componentStore.setState({movies: []});
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have a composition with a component-store? (I mean without the use `extends` keyword which does inheritance) and if so, how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the component-store, then yes, it's the only way.

The extend adds this methods https://next.ngrx.io/api/component-store/ComponentStore.